# magento 2 do not send Order mail for failed payment

Tags: payment, magento-2.2.5

i have added some payment gateway modules, where my payment was failed still "Order mail" goes to user, is there way to stop this when payment gets failed.

I can not see any option in admin for it . Please help.

Comment: you can configure Payment Failed Email, a notification email that is auto-sent to the recipients

Comment: This message informs the failure of the payemnt method when customers use it in the checkout process. To make sure it send to custombers’ inbox, you should enable SMTP.